# Why does Visual Build Pro build wrong project in "VisBuildPro Project" step?

Tags: visual-build-professional

I have created a Visual Build Professional 8 script that uses the "System" > "VisBuildPro Project" step to call another build script.  I browsed to the correct build script to be run for the step in the Project tab of the properties the "VisBuildPro Project" step and clicked apply but when I run the main script the step does not call the correct build script. It keeps calling the script I created.

Has anyone had this issue and do you have a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have a 64-bit OS and originally the 32-bit version of Visual Build Pro was installed on the machine then the 64-bit version was installed which caused issues when launching another script.  I was able to discover this when I ran Visual Build Pro from the command line for my script.  I uninstalled both versions and just reinstalled the 64-bit version and this fixed my problem.